# R: how do you apply a function to a vector and get a vector of different length?

Tags: r

I have a list of means, for example

```
avgs = c(1,2,3)
```

and a function:

```
simulate <- function (avg)
{ rnorm(n=10,m=avg,sd=1) }
```

What is the best way to get a vector of 30 values, rather than a multidimensional array from
`sapply(avgs,simulate)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, just take advantage of the fact that `rnorm` is vectorized and thus will accept entire vectors as arguments:

```
rnorm(30, avgs, 1)
```

You can also remove dimensions from your matrix with `c`:

```
c(sapply(avgs, simulate))
```

but this approach is slower and less direct.

Comment: Mayebe he could use `return()` in his function